# Aggregate/annotate project profit

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm having a hard time aggregating project `profit`, so I can do more calculation with the result.

```
total_potential_profit = Project.objects.filter(created__year=year, created__month=month, client_sub_org__lead_contact__account_handler=user_id).aggregate(Sum('profit_aux'))
```

and this return None as a result, I'm not shure If I'm doing the right thing with aggregation, it seems that annotation is more appropriate in this filter, but that is also returning `None` as a result.
The model that I'm filtering on is

```
class Project(models.Model):
    client_sub_org = models.ForeignKey(ClientSubOrganization)
    profit_aux = models.DecimalField('profit aux', max_digits=20 decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and the `user_id` that I'm pulling out is from these models, client sub organization:

```
class ClientSubOrganization(models.Model):
    lead_contact = models.OneToOneField(LeadContact, blank=True, null=True)
```

and Lead Contact

```
class LeadContact(models.Model):
    account_handler = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='handling_leads', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

What would be the proper way of doing this?

Comment: what does `total_potential_profit = Project.objects.filter(created__year=year, created__month=month, client_sub_org__lead_contact__account_handler=user_id)` without  `.aggregate` gives

Comment: the result is `total_potential_profit: []`

Comment: If it is empty it means there is no data for the corresponding filter query. That's why `aggregate` results in None.

Comment: yea, the whole calculation is wrong, so I need to go back to the drawing board with this